# How to get the latest record and update a column using Sequelize

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, sequelize.js

Using sequelize how to find the `latest` record from a table and update the `status` column. While running the code I am getting `latestRecord` as undefined. Any advise will be really helpful !

```
app.put("/service/activeStatus", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
    const activeStatus = req.body.status;
    var latestRecord = NominationSessionModel.findAll({
      limit:1,
      order:
       Sequelize.literal('nominationStartDate DESC')
    })

    const updateSession = await NominationSessionModel.update(
        {
          ...req.body,
          status:activeStatus
        },
        { where: { id: latestRecord[0].id } }
    );
    res.status(200).send(updateSession);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({fail: e.message});
  }
});
```

[image]

Tried another way:

```
app.put("/service/activeStatus", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const activeStatus = req.body.status;
    var latestRecord = NominationSessionModel.findAll({
      attributes: [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('nominationStartDate')), 'status', 'id']
    });
 
    const updateSession = await NominationSessionModel.update(
        {status: activeStatus},
        {
          where: {id: latestRecord[latestRecord.length-1].id}
        });
    console.log("Getdateatus:" + updateSession);
    res.status(200).send(updateSession);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({fail: e.message});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Sequelize, as much as I know about `mongodb`, conditions in your code is similar.

I do not know why you have written this:

```
                            where: { id: latestRecord[0].id }
```

This does not give you the latest record that you have entered. It will give the condition where `[0]` which is the data of the 1st record in it. not the latest one.

So I think the condition should be:

```
                   where: {id: latestRecord[latestRecord.length-1].id}
```

I think this should work.

---

EDIT:

```
where: {"_id": latestRecord[latestRecord.length-1]._id}
```

try this and checkout.

Comment: I will and reply you in few hours

Comment: Is your latestRecord and array?

Comment: `var latestRecord = NominationSessionModel.findAll()` Try this and see

Comment: I cannot see any screenshot.

Comment: Added another way i have tried, but unable to resolve the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978567/browser-reload-does-not-get-back-to-selected-page-goes-to-default-homepage-r I too am facing the same issue. My list is undefined and cannot get the data related to it

Comment: use `let` instead of `var` and try out

Comment: [[{"MAX(nominationStartDate)":"2021-08-30T08:43:44.000Z","status":1,"id":1}],[{"MAX(nominationStartDate)":"2021-08-30T08:43:44.000Z","status":1,"id":1}]]

Comment: I have edited my answer. just try that out and see