# Browser Reload: Does not get back to selected page, goes to default homepage - ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

I am new in using ReactJS and learning it bit by bit. I have 3 pages: `homepage`, `contacts` and `moviesDetails`. When I travel through `contacts` or `moviesDetails` and hit browser's reload, it gets me back to `homepage` which I do not want. I want it to stay on the same page which I am in.

If I am in `contacts` page, and hit browser's reload, I want it to stay on `contacts` page. I do not want it to go to `homepage`.

I don't know how to store the opened page's path in `localStorage`. I need help here as I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Following is `App.js` code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Homepage from "./homepage/Homepage";
import Contacts from "./contacts/Contacts";
import PrivateRoute from "./private-route/PrivateRoute";
import MoviesDetails from "./MoviesDetails/MoviesDetails";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/moviesDetails" component={MoviesDetails} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Following is `contacts.js` code: (All respective components are being imported)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { changeHeaderName} from '../../actions/homepageActions';    

class contacts extends Component {    
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data:"",
      value: 0,
      date: "",
      errorList: {}
    };
  }    
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.header("Contacts");
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <TabPanel value={this.state.value}>
            <Grid container
              justify="flex-start"
              alignItems="center"
            >
              <Grid xs={6}>
                <Typography>
                  (Names here)
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
        
              <Grid xs={3}>
                <Typography>
                  Contacts
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={5}>
                <Typography>
                  (All the contacts are listed here)
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
        </TabPanel>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {mainUser: state.auth.mainUser}
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {header})(configurations);
```

Following is `store.js` code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    (b&&a()) ||compose)
);

export default store;
```

And `store` exported above is been used in `index.js` file.

Given the above code, I do not want my loaded page go back to the `homepage`. I want to stay on the same page. Browser reload gets me back to "/homepage" instead of "/contacts". Browser reload gets me back to "/homepage" instead of "/moviesDetails".

I am not using any hooks here. So I don't want my code to be in hooks. Just a simple `react.js` code.

---

EDIT NO: 1

Following is my `PrivateRoute.js` code

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authentic, ...rest}) => (

    <Route 
        {...rest}
        render={ props => 
            authentic.isAuthenticated === true ? (
                    <div>
                        <Component {...props} />
                    </div>
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/" />
            )
        }
    />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
    authentic: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
  
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    authentic: state.auth
});
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

---

EDIT NO: 2

Following is `redux store provider` : (this is in `index.js` file)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/App';
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

EDIT NO: 3

Following is `MoviesDetails` component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import { moviesList } from "./actions/moviesActions";

class MoviesDetails extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      skip: 0,
      limit: 10,
      pageNumber: 0,
      value: '',
      nameMovie:"",
      genre:"",
      ratings:"",
      numberOfSongs:"",
      releaseDate:"",     
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {this.fetchRecords();}

  fetchRecords=async()=>{
    let payload ={
      nameMovie:this.state.nameMovie,
      genre:this.state.genre,
      ratings:this.state.ratings,
      numberOfSongs :this.state.numberOfSongs ,
      releaseDate : this.state.releaseDate,
      skip : this.state.limit * this.state.pageNumber,
      limit: this.state.limit,
    }
   await  this.props.moviesList(payload);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (    
      <div>
        <div  />
        <Container >
          <TableContainer>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>Movie Name</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Genre</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Song Count</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Ratings</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Release Date</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {this.props.movies.moviesList.map((movie, index) => {
                  return (
                    <TableRow >
                      <TableCell>
                        {nameMovie}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{genre}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{numberOfSongs}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{ratings}</TableCell>                          
                      <TableCell>{releaseDate}</TableCell>                          
                    </TableRow>
                  )
                })}
              </TableBody>                  
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    movie: state.movie,
    adim: state.auth.admin,
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {moviesList })(MoviesDetails);
```

I handle my `moviesDetails` tab like this:

```
handleMovies = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); 
this.props.history.push("/moviesDetails"); }
```

Comment: Recommend you create a minimal app in https://codesandbox.io/ to reproduce the issue so that people here could help to debug it easily. Route conf in App.js looks good, the issue might be caused by code in other files. You can search the usage of 'history' in your code to check whether it's being called at initial phase.

Comment: 'history' being called at initial stage means?

Comment: 'history' is an object which you can get the current path the app stays, switch page from one to another by calling its method like push. More details https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history.

Comment: How do i store that path in localStorage?

Comment: Actually you don't have to store any path in localstorage. When the app get reloaded, it stays at the last path. This is ensured by the browser, like what you say on this page on stackoverflow. When you hit the reload the page will stay on the question forever. Unless addiation script get exected to switch the page. That's what I suggest you to check whether some code called 'history' object to do the switch.

Comment: Okay. I'll read about and can ask you if I have any doubts right?

Comment: What component or method is being used when browser reload is hit? @Oluwafemi Sule need your help here.

Comment: My guess is your `PrivateRoute` is bouncing users back to the main/home page before you've had a chance to hydrate any authentication state you previously persisted to localStorage, or you aren't persisting your state and since it live entirely in memory is wiped out when the page/app reloads. Can you share your `PrivateRoute` component, and any reducer/middleware you are using to persist your redux store to localStorage and how you initialize state from localStorage? (I'm guessing you aren't initializing from localStorage since you've `const initialState = {};` in your store code.

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the question, and have put the code for "PrivateRoute". Can you just tell me what I have done wrong there?

Comment: Yes, so the `authentic` value from state is injected as a prop. When the app reloads, if you are not using a "populated" initial state then this will be the default initial state value and user is getting bounced back to "/". Are you persisting your redux store to localStorage in any way?

Comment: NO actually. there is not persisting of state anywhere. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I figured as much. Can you add your redux store provider component to your question? I can make a suggestion from there.

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the store provider component in EDIT NO : 2 . I really have no idea what the problem is. This is my important project and cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist your redux state to local storage when it updates, and initialize your store from local storage when app loads.

Minimal Redux Store Persistence Example:

Create a "middle" component to handle persisting state updates to localStorage.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux];

const StorePersister = ({ children }) => {
  const state = useSelector(state => state);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('myState', JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state]);

  return children;
};
```

index - wrap the `App` component with the store persister.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './components/App';
import StorePersister from './components/StorePersister';
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StorePersister>
      <App />
    </StorePersister>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Initialize state from local storage. If there is no "myState" key or the parsing returns `null` then the empty object (`{}`) will be used as a fallback.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myState')) || {};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    (b&&a()) || compose
  )
);

export default store;
```

There is also a [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) package out there that offers a bit of customization for what gets persisted to and initialized from the persistence.

Comment: Okay. I will try this out. Thank you for answering. I hope you will be available if I have any doubts if you don't mind. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This worked. But there is one problem that came. I have linked my database. But whenever I navigate to "/moviesDetails" I do not see any data in the front-end. Earlier it was working. I tried your code, and the "/moviesDetails" is not working anymore. It just gives me buffering. SInce the "initialState" is changed, it does not show me any data in "/moviesDetails"

Comment: @Itidi Can you clarify what isn't working? Is this something specific to what the `MoviesDetails` component does?

Comment: As I said I have 3 pages, when reload is hit, it redirects me to /homepage. For /contacts it works fine. Also it works fine for /moviesDetails. Its does not go to /hompage. But /moviesDetails have data which is connected to database. If I hit reload, /moviesDetails page is blank. Nothing can be seen. The all the data present is not to be seen. Its all set to null.

Comment: Database connection goes when I hit reload

Comment: @Itidi Can you add the `MoviesDetails` component to your question? Is this where the "connection to database" is made? If not, can you include that code and logic?

Comment: I have edited the question in EDIT NO: 3, there I have added the component of "MoviesDetails"

Comment: @Itidi Is `moviesList` an action to fetch the data you say is the "connected to database? Is the `componentDidMount` running again after reload?

Comment: I have edited my code in same way as your answer. But the table seems to be blank. The page itself is empty. That's because of the changes made in "intitialState". I don't know how to proceed now

Comment: Yes. it fetches data from the database

Comment: @Itidi I don't understand. Previously your initial state was an empty object, so how was the page working  previously? Is it something to do with `this.props.movies.moviesList` but you map only a `movie` and `adim` prop from state? Is `this.props.movies` being passed from elsewhere?

Comment: It seems your original issue of reloading the page and not getting redirected is resolved. This new issue of getting the state mapping correct seems an extracurricular activity. A new post on stackoverflow specific to this new issue would be better for you as you'd get more eyes on it more quickly. If you do post a new question for this specific issue then feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when I can.

Comment: Once I login , the token related to the user is stored. In "/contacts" its just the text been seen and reloading works fine there. But for "/moviesDetails", there is an action "moviesList" been called to fetch records from the database. So in "componentDidMount" fetchRecords() is been called to fetch data from the database and display in the table.

Comment: So, with your respectives changes as in your answer, reloading does not work for "/moviesDetails". When I have logged in, data in "/moviesDetails" can be seen perfectly. The moment I hit reload, all the data is gone. Table itself is not seen. Everything seems to be blank

Comment: @Itidi Right, this seems to be because `this.props.movies.moviesList` is empty. Where does this prop come from? I don't see how anything could render at all *before* any page reloads. Something is missing.

Comment: I have:    handleMovies = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/moviesDetails");
  }
This is when I go to "/moviesDetails"

Comment: Thank you very much for you comments and answer. I have figured out what is the problem, and with you answer it has worked for me. It gets reloaded to the same page and also get the data in "/moviesDetails"